# Was Alex Forrest actually pregnant?

Tags: plot-explanation, fatal-attraction

Throughout [Fatal Attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_Attraction), we see the desperate measures that Alex will go to to get any type of attention or reaction from Dan after the affair is over.

Alex proceeds to tell Dan that she's pregnant and she gives him her gynecologists business card to call him.

There is also a scene depicting Dan rummaging through her apartment and he sees an E.P.T. pregnancy test in the medicine cabinet, but, it doesn't show anything else.

Dan admits to his friend that he did infact call the gynecologist.

> **Dan**:  So, you know what I did?  I called the Doctor.  Do you know what
>   he says?  Congratulations.  I can't even imagine what she told him.

**Is there any evidence that Alex actually is pregnant with Dan's child?** We see the desperate measures that Alex resorts to throughout the movie. I would see it being completely feasible for her to create a phony business card with a fictitious Doctor. **Wouldn't a phantom pregnancy be another one of her desperate measures?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/430513.Fatal_Attraction?from_search=true&from_srp=true&qid=Ib0Fa1y4dl&rank=1) we see him speaking to the gynaecologist. There doesn't seem to be any ambiguity. She's confirmed as pregnant and has told the doctor that Dan is the father.

> Before he left, he phoned the gynecologist whose card she had given
> him. He said he was a friend of Alex Forrest’s. Before he got any
> farther, the doctor said, “Ah, you must be Dan. Congratulations.”

In the [original script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/fatal-attraction-1987.pdf) he sees a verified pregnancy test. She didn't know that he would be going through her things, so it's unlikely that she would have faked it.

> In the bathroom, he looks at all her many pills. Something catches his eye in the medicine cabinet. Closeup: A home pregnancy test. She was telling the truth.

It's possible that this was all some manner of elaborate ruse but it seems vanishingly unlikely.

Answer (score -6):

EVERY one knows the original ending of Fatal Attraction is

Alex kills herself.

No boiled bunny. No drowning. No wife shooting the harlot.

She dies.

Now, reading an article I see someone says

"stalking Dan at work, calling him at all hours, faking a pregnancy, stalking his wife Beth at her place of employment, even picking up Dan and Beth’s daughter Ellen at school"

FAKING a pregnancy? She didn't "fake" anything. She was pregnant.

It's based on Madame Butterfly.

She's pregnant. That's made clear in the film.

Comment: There are 2 different endings for the movie  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_Attraction#Alternate_ending

Comment: Could you explain *where* in the film it's made clear that she's pregnant? Simply saying "it's made clear" isn't really enough evidence. Also, I don't see how the film's alternate endings are relevant to the question.